# Is there any way to cast a relationship table attribute in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, casting, query-builder, eloquent-relationship

I have a users model with a carts function that returns all carts detail after joining three tables. I would like to convert an attribute to an array which is a JSON type.

**Example:** I have four table **users**, **carts**, **item_detail_informations**, and **item_details** tables where item_details table **picture column is a JSON type**. I want to convert picture JSON data to an array. 
[image]

My carts function is like this.

```
public function carts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Cart')
    ->join('item_detail_informations', 'carts.item_detail_information_id','=','item_detail_informations.id')
    ->join('item_details', 'item_detail_informations.item_detail_id','=','item_details.id')
    ->join('items', 'item_details.item_id','=','items.id')
    ->select('carts.user_id','carts.item_detail_information_id','item_detail_informations.size','item_detail_informations.price','item_detail_informations.item_detail_id', 'item_details.picture','item_details.item_id')
    ;
}
```

I am trying to cast picture attribute like this.

```
protected $casts = [
    'item_details.picture' => 'array',
];
```

**But it's not working. Is there any way to convert the picture attribute to JSON?**

Comment: You need to casts attribute in `ItemDetail` model, and remove all joins and do via `with` eloquent method. So `return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Cart')->with(['items', 'item_details', 'item_detail_informations'])`

Comment: There is no direct relationship with the user  table and items table so I am getting `Call to undefined relationship [items] on model [App\Models\Cart]`

Comment: Inside the carts model, there is a relationship method name `itenDetailInformation`. so If i write like this `return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Cart')->with(['itemDetailInformation'])` i can access item_detail_informations table but I can't not access other table.

Comment: Ok then just add other relations. With join you can't mutate eloquent because `join` work with `QueryBuilder` and you need `EloquentQueryBuilder`. So in that case, add other relations and eloquent will do else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all joins in carts method(instead use eager loading via with). And cast attribute in the ItemDetail model. it will automatically picked up when you call carst method. Hope it will help you

Comment: I am getting this error `Call to undefined relationship [items] on model [App\Models\Cart]` when using ->with() keyword.

Comment: Do you have items method on Cart model?
`public function items(){
return $this->hasMany(Item::class)
}`

Comment: no, carts model have `itemDetailInformation` method, ItemDetailInformation model have `itemDetail` method and itemDetail model have `item` method

Comment: So you can call this relation like `with(itemDetailInformation.itemDetail.item)`separated by dots

Comment: Nice, I get all data but I want to select specific columns instead of full table 
like this `->select(
            'carts.user_id',
            'carts.item_detail_information_id',
            'item_detail_informations.size',
            'item_detail_informations.price',
            'item_detail_informations.item_detail_id',
            'item_details.picture',
            'item_details.item_id'
        )`

Comment: you can use [api resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) for mapping the result data. There are very usefull

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) instead